# How can i extend components/features from a angular library that should be used by the library

Tags: angular

I have created a base angular project with navigation and some list components.
I packed them as library and i am using them now within a new project.

I would like to add new features to existing components of the library but the rendering component for lists is still sitting within the library. It should see the new implementation and render it instead of the base component.

I dont want to duplicate the whole structure on the library again in my project.